# Positioning of CSS image div

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: Fixed it, I am daft. It was because h1 is below the div.**

So I was making some web page for a school project and I keep running into this annoying problem, I am trying to make an image gallery on the page with multiple thumbnails all in ordered categories on a page. e.g. since it is video game themed it should be like heroes and maps. Problem is when I place an image, the image pushes the text I had at the top of the screen under it, probably a really simple solution to this just need a bit of help. thanks. [here is the link](http://prntscr.com/c4dne3)

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bigNoodle;
    src: url(Font/big_noodle_titling_oblique.ttf);
}

#splash {

    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: white url('Pictures/logo.png') center no-repeat;
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: bigNoodle;
    color: #939393;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;


}

body {
    background: url('Pictures/bg.jpg') center fixed no-repeat;

}

h1 {
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: bigNoodle;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #F99E1A;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

div.picture img {

    height: 200px;



}
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='anim.js'></script>
    <title>Wiki</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Pictures/logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="splash">Click to continue...</div>

<div class="picture">
    <img src="Pictures/Heroes.jpg">
</div>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code? And can you explain what you want to happen instead of the text moving out of the way of the image?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit yours to include a [mcve].

Comment: I want the images to be below the text as the text is the Header of the page, I also was the images to be in two side by side categories in the middle of the page, will post code now

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in multiple ways

Way 1:

You can apply z-index for text

for instance text 'welcome' is there inside h1

```
h1
{
z-index:999;
}
```

way 2:
take your image as background of div

https://jsfiddle.net/ogyk1914/

Comment: z-index by itself will do nothing.